# Weak convergence of measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that the measure $\mu_n$ weakly convergences to the measure $\mu$. Does the following hold?

1. For any measurable set $A$, $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \mu_n(A)\ge \mu(A)$?
2. For any measurable set $A$, $\liminf_{n\to \infty} \mu_n(A)\le \mu(A)$?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.  Let $\mu_n$ be a point mass at $1/n$ and $\mu$ be a point mass at $0$.  A counterexample to (1) is the singleton $A = \{0\}$ and a counterexample to (2) is $A = (0,1]$.

For some more detailed information you can read about the [portmanteau theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures)